# How to get a list of recent files in MFC

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc, dialog

I am trying to build a welcome page (which is CDHTmlDialog based) and in that welcome page i want to present a list of my recent files.
it should look like Adobe Reader welcome page.

I tried to get the recent file list by getting the MRU list and it's not going so well.

```
LoadStdProfileSettings(5);  // Load standard INI file options (including MRU)

m_pRecentUrls = new CRecentFileList('0', L"Recent URL List", L"%d", 5, URL_MRU_ENTRY_LEN);
m_pRecentUrls->ReadList();
```

Answer (score 4):

The list of recent files in MFC is maintained in `CRecentFileList* CWinApp::m_pRecentFileList`. You can access it by index like this:

```
CString CMyApp::GetRecentFile( int index ) const  
{  
    return (*m_pRecentFileList)[ index ];  
}
```